# Pantheon Drupal Clone Database and Files

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, pantheon

We are using **Pantheon** and **Drupal**. I have added new users to the *live* site, and new content to the *dev* site. How do I promote the content to the *live* site without overwriting the new users?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about that before you started entering content (including new users) on 2 different website.

With Drupal it's very hard (almost impossible) merging 2 databases into one because of it's complex structure, shared node ids between different content types...

Check out "Migrate" module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate

and it's submodule "Drupal to Drupal":
https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d